# Why is Popen in python not async when calling stdout on Ubuntu?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

In python when using Popen to start a subprocess from which i want to capture the output (as it happens not afterwards)
Iterating over the stdout is waiting for the process to finish under ubuntu but under windows it does it correctly.
How to make it work async with ubuntu?

The script running

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen("python3 test.py", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True,universal_newlines=True,shell=True)
for line in process.stdout:
    print('got output:',line)
```

test.py

```
import time
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
    time.sleep(i)
```

I tried to change the buffersize and so on as well as asyncio, but nothing seems to work. (python version is 3.10)

using python3 -u  fixed it!

Comment: Side-note: There is *zero* reason to use `shell=True` here. Don't. It adds overhead and more potential buffering issues. Just pass `["python3", "-u", "test.py"]` as the command, and drop the `shell=True`. Also, `text` and `universal_newlines` mean the same thing; if you're already requiring a version modern enough to recognize `text=True`, drop the `universal_newlines=True` argument.